# Delphi - How to get a image for a cxGrid column?

Tags: delphi, ms-access, delphi-2010, tcxgrid

I have a TcxGrid component to show data of a MS Access table. One of this columns have a picture. The column "Properties" of this column is marked as "ButtonEdit".

I don't want to use a BlobEdit. I want to create another form, for display this picture. It will be opened by OnButtonClick() event of the grid column. But, I don't know how to get the column content (as TStream or other type), or the column name/field name in the OnButtonClick() event. I can't fix the column name, because it's a "generic" grid for show any Access table.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It will be nice to understand your question better if you can post your code. But offcourse You can get column contents easily by using FieldByName method. Try to use that.

Answer (score 0):

You did not say how you load the data into the grid, but to get the cell content you can use:

```
  VarAsType(cxGrid1TableView1.DataController.Values[cxGrid1TableView1.Controller.FocusedRecordIndex,cxGrid1TableView1.Controller.FocusedColumnIndex],varString)
```